# trying to do a shallow copy on list in python

Tags: python, shallow-copy

So i copied using copy.copy which is shallow but if i change the value in one the value in the other won't get changed.

```
import copy
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
b=copy.copy(a)
print id(a[0])==id(b[0])
```

now i get true as output.Since the address of a[0] and b[0] is same then if i change the value of one the other must also change.

```
b[0]=55
print[a]
print[b]
```

Output:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
[55,2,3,4,5]
```

So why is it like that?

Answer (score 7):

`id(a[0])==id(b[0])` returns `True` because you're comparing the identities of the integers (`1` in this case) not the lists, and integers are interned (as an implementation detail) within the range of -5 to 256 as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers).

`copy.copy` returns a shallow copy of the list so `id(a) == id(b)` returns `False`.

You can see a visualization of this I made on [Python tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20copy%0Aa%3D%5B1,2,3,4,5%5D%0Ab%3Dcopy.copy(a%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=3&heapPrimitives=true&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false).

Answer (score 4):

A shallow copy of a list **is not** the same list. A shallow copy of a list creates another list but links to the original contained elements. A deep copy instead copy also the elements. So, `a` and `b` point to the same elements, but are different list.

[image: shallow copy vs deep copy]

So when you change `b` you are not changing `a`. What you want is just this:

```
b = a
b[0] = 55
print(a)      # [55, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(b)      # [55, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: okay so if i change peggy to bunny in shallow copy it should affect both the bags right?

Comment: @ashwinmurthy The fact is that you are not changing the element. `b[0] = 55` actually changes the pointer of `b` to another element `55`, but the old one is still there, so `a` still points to the old one.

Comment: thanks that clarified my doubt.

Answer (score 2):

you get same `id` because `integers` are [immutable](https://codehabitude.com/2013/12/24/python-objects-mutable-vs-immutable/) in python. There is only one `1` (or any integer). If you think about it, you will see that anyway it does not make sense to keep multiple values of a constant integer.

for example

```
a = 1
b = 1
id(a) == id(b)
True
```

Here although `a` and `b` are completely independent variables, since they store the same integer values their ids are the same

You can modify the values of `a` and `b` independently as you would expect.

```
b = 2
id(a) == id(b)
False
```

Now if we have a third variable, say `c`

```
c = 2
id(c) == id(b)
True
```

This behaviour actually has nothing to do with shallow/deep copy.
As another example, using dictionaries

```
d = {'a': 1}
e = {'c': 1}
id(d['a']) == id(e['c'])
True
```

Answer (score 1):

`copy.copy(a)` create another list, it does not have the same address. Only the content are the same (different from deepcopy that recreate list and content).

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b=a
>>> id(a) == id(b) #True

>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b=copy.copy(a)
>>> id(a) == id(b) #False
```

Comment: How can you explain that when you create two lists that have the same elements, the id is the same ?

Comment: oups, my example was wrong for that part.